# How to get extent out of GeoTiff

Tags: geotiff-tiff

How do I get the extent out of the GeoTiff format? I want something like this:

```
Extent(293518.1886150768,5680494.194041155,890338.5054657329,6267530.571271311)
```

AKA the xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax coordinates from the GeoTiff?

Edit: I'm implementing my own reader so I will need to know how the file format tells me this information.

Comment: Do you have a particular software or API in mind?

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear, editing the question.

Comment: Listgeo gives you a rather low level access to geotiff tags http://www.remotesensing.org/geotiff/listgeo.html

Comment: hi, yes the problem is that I don't know **which** tags give me the information. Do you know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tags you're interested in are: ModelTiepointTag, ModelPixelScaleTag, and ModelTransformationTag. The specification describes how they stored the information:

http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/19-008r4/19-008r4.html#_raster_to_model_coordinate_transformation_requirements

> For most common applications, the transformation between raster space
> and model space may be defined with a set of raster-to-model tiepoints
> and scaling parameters. The ModelTiepointTag and ModelPixelScaleTag
> may be used for this purpose.
>
> Alternatively, the ModelTransformationTag may be used to specify the
> transformation matrix between the raster space (and its dependent
> pixel-value space) and the (possibly 3D) model space.
>
> The ModelTiepointTag SHALL have 6 values for each of the tiepoints
>
> The ModelPixelScaleTag SHALL have 3 values representing the scale factor in the X, Y, and Z directions
>
> The ModelTransformationTag SHALL have 16 values representing the terms of the 4 by 4 transformation matrix. The terms SHALL be in row-major order

You could have a look at how GDAL implements them in this file:

http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/frmts/gtiff/geotiff.cpp

Comment: I'm done with the implementation and these are the tags I used. What happened was that my reader didn't have to do the actual projections so the extent was all I needed, and to get them I used the tags you mentioned above.

Answer (score 20):

You can use [Rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) to get the bounding box as follows:

```
import rasterio

dataset = rasterio.open('example.tif')

>>> dataset.bounds
BoundingBox(left=358485.0, bottom=4028985.0, right=590415.0, top=4265115.0)
```

Answer (score 19):

Building on what @David mentioned you may use open source [gdal](http://www.gdal.org/) library using [python module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/) to get image extent like this:

```
import gdal
from gdalconst import GA_ReadOnly

data = gdal.Open('C:/Temp/myimage.tif', GA_ReadOnly)
geoTransform = data.GetGeoTransform()
minx = geoTransform[0]
maxy = geoTransform[3]
maxx = minx + geoTransform[1] * data.RasterXSize
miny = maxy + geoTransform[5] * data.RasterYSize
print [minx, miny, maxx, maxy]
data = None
```

> [-86.20782844487971, 40.7246942570317, -84.5446284448797,
>   41.8290942570317]

Reference: [Find Extents of GDAL Raster](https://www.siafoo.net/snippet/69/rev/1)

Comment: Hi, thanks. As I have mentioned before I need the Keys/Tags that correspond to these values. The GeoTiff has a ModelTransformationTag, is that the transformation tag your using?

Answer (score 1):

Using the `arcpy` site package in Python, you can accomplish this by converting your geotiff to a raster object and using the `extent` and `*max`&`*min` classes.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\path\to\ws'

rasters = arcpy.ListRasters()

for ras in rasters:
    f = arcpy.Raster(ras)
    xmin = f.extent.XMin
    ymin = f.extent.YMin
    xmax = f.extent.XMax
    ymax = f.extent.YMax
    rectangle = "%s %s %s %s" % (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
```

Comment: It's going to be faster if you set f equal to the extent, instead of accessing it each time. I had code similar to this in a tight loop (building raster indices), and it cut execution time in half by making that simple change. It's actually a two liner with `getattr()`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Paul.  My benchmark tests indicate 0.05 seconds to extract the extent using this method.  Two-liners are not necessarily better than larger sections of code--after all "Readability counts." (from the Zen of Python: `import this`)

Comment: Huh, I noticed a substantial difference in my benchmarks over 1000 rasters. But for a few, yeah there won't be any noticeable difference.

Comment: The source for `import this` is amusing indeed. ;) I find `[getattr(extent, x) for x in ("XMin", "YMin", "XMax", "YMax")]` pretty readable, but that's just me.

Comment: I'm sorry but I want to know how the arcpy library does this, I'm writing my own reader in Scala.

Answer (score 1):

I see that no one has mentioned yet to use GDAL's `GetEnvelope()`. From the [Docs](https://gdal.org/doxygen/classOGRGeometry.html#aa3d42b06ae6f7bbef6d1a2886da8d398):

> Computes and returns the bounding envelope for this geometry in the passed psEnvelope structure.
> This method is the same as the C function OGR_G_GetEnvelope().

So what you want to do is:

```py
(xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax) = geom.GetEnvelope()
```

I feel this is more direct to what you need than using GeoTransform and doing some math to get the corners.