# Finding overlapping areas between two or more GeoTIFF files

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, overlapping-features

How can one programmatically understand overlapping areas between two or more GeoTIFF files captured at various timestamps for the same location?

Comment: If you can provide some additional details about the problem you are trying to solve it will help community members provide more useful answers.

Comment: Are you looking for any Python solution or looking for something more specific like `gdal` or `arcpy`?

Answer (score 1):

To compare the overlap between two images find the extent of each image in the same coordinate system and then compare the coordinates. [This question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104362/how-to-get-extent-out-of-geotiff) has some examples of how to get the extent using python.

Comment: This is probably the most straightforward solution. However it does not take into account NoData values. Maybe the two rasters overlap in their NoData values, which depending on the situation, could or could not be what @Gaurav refers to as overlapping areas.

Comment: That's a great point. This is somewhat clunky, but to find the extent of non-NoData areas one could check the rows and columns for a mean != NoData, and then back calculate on the coordinates. For example 5 rows of NoData at 30m pixels would mean subtract 150m from the original extent coordinate.